# how do i open a different host session from shell script and start a process on it

Tags: scripts

I want to open a new session and run a process on it as part of the shell script.How can that be acheived.

I need open a session with test@Testhost and run a process ./testprocess on that separate session.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh  test@Testhost ./testprocess`

The ssh client takes an optional command and parameters. You could experiment:

`ssh  test@Testhost ls`

`ssh  test@Testhost ls -l`

This works best if you have set up ssh for password-less login using public keys.

Comment: @sмurf.....but will this open a new session?

Comment: Yes, it will open a new session on Testhost. If the process is long-running but you want your call to return immediately consider wrapping `./testprocess` in another shell script and use `nohup`